# How to you add a parameter to an executable in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

How to you add a parameter to an executable in Windows 10?

Once you select *Properties* by right-clicking on a program's icon (or its shortcut), there is no field to do this.
I am using a non-privileged account.

Comment: for some shortcuts, created in startmenu and system link don't support this. you must create your own shortcuts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only add parameters to shortcuts, not to normal exe properties. So select the exe, do a right click select copy go to desktop, make a rightclick and select `paste shortcut`

[image]

Now do a right click on the shortcut and select properties.

At `target` you must add the parameters after the exe name.

[image]

In this demo I created a `Explorer.exe` shortcut and added `/n,/e,C:\` to start Explorer directly in `C:\`.

Comment: I think I found the reason for my problem (see my answer below); I'm marking your answer as accepted anyway as it was useful.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that, in Windows 10, shortcuts of the shortcuts which are in the Start menu behave this way: their *Target* field is greyed out (and, additionally, it shows no path to the exe, only the program name):

[image]

So, to add params to an executable's shortcut, one needs to find the original exe and make the shortcut from it.

In previous versions of Windows, making a shortcut of a shortcut of an exe linked back to the original executable itself.

Comment: that are the shortcuts created by installers on desktop/startmenu, that are blocked. if you create your own one, it should always work.

Comment: Nope. I'm creating them by hand on the Desktop or on my homedir, and all of them are like this.

Comment: hm, that's wired. can you use your phone to create a video on how you create the shortcut

Comment: I think I found the issue. Edited my answer.

Comment: this is what I already told you. that why I told you to create a new shortcut on your own