# How to Disable Permanently the Chromium Popup after Crash or Hard boot?

Tags: raspberry-pi, chromium

I am aware of post
[Disable Google Chrome session restore functionality](https://superuser.com/questions/461035/disable-google-chrome-session-restore-functionality)
and I have tried to apply most of I saw there **without success**. The nasty annoying popup lives.
This is on a Raspberry pi

Can someone tell me why the following is not working.

the startup file on the pi is **/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart** and it contains the following...

```
# fix chromium popup on hard reboot
sed -i 's/"exited_cleanly":false/"exited_cleanly":true/' ~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences
sed -i 's/"exit_type":"Crashed"/"exit_type":"Normal"/' ~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences
sed -i 's/"exited_cleanly":false/"exited_cleanly":true/' ~/.config/chromium/'Local State'


# chromium-browser 
chromium-browser --start-fullscreen --kiosk --disable-session-crashed-bubble http://mydomain/?cat=SLOWTV
```

I have tried each sed line on the command line and it works editing the file.
Is there a possibility they are failing silently when running at startup?

I have also tried also the following $HOME variable

```
sed -i 's/"exited_cleanly":false/"exited_cleanly":true/' $HOME/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences
sed -i 's/"exit_type":"Crashed"/"exit_type":"Normal"/' $HOME/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences
sed -i 's/"exited_cleanly":false/"exited_cleanly":true/' $HOME/.config/chromium/'Local State'
```

and the following using a hardcoded path

```
sed -i 's/"exited_cleanly":false/"exited_cleanly":true/'  /home/pi/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences
sed -i 's/"exit_type":"Crashed"/"exit_type":"Normal"/'  /home/pi/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences
sed -i 's/"exited_cleanly":false/"exited_cleanly":true/'  /home/pi/.config/chromium/'Local State'
```

I have tried --incognito but I get another different chromium team stupid popup about allowing my site to write to disk, every single time, ( --incognito clears the cache)

I have tried

```
chmod -w ~/.config/chromium/'Local State' 
chmod -w ~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences
```

After running the sed and verifying the json variable are correct, but chromium has super power and it changes the access rights of these two files back to -rw------ from -r-------

No matter what I did, every time I hit the power switch, (bloody pi has no soft-reboot) and the pi reboots I get the popup

```
Restore page?
Chromium didn't shutdown correctly.
```

I have already wasted well over a day on this.  This is becoming ridiculously painful.
Thank you for any hint fixing my failures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although, I created a user without sudo power
The following should probably equally well on the default pi user.

After manually exiting Chromium on the GUI (ie. clean exit)

```
su
(note: super-user remain in current user path, now using relative to local path)
chattr  +i  .config/chromium/Default/Preferences
chattr  +i  .config/chromium/'Local State'
```

If you never created a password for the root on your pi do the following and you will have the password for the su command above.

```
sudo passwd root
```

I have filed a bug against Chromium :D
This is unnecessary pain and waste of internet and people time/energy and well being. :lol:

Comment: I used your solution but unfortunately all installed chrome extensions go when I restart the computer.

Comment: Salam, I did not install any extensions so I cannot speak to that.  I noticed that gmail will silently log you out after it takes your password.  I have to test whether the above is the cause of that. I like the fact I have not seen the popup since then though.  I am waiting for an Android TV Box $39.99 to see how it works with my site.  The Pi's have been a pain to say the least. Just today I noticed the latest chromium does not render some simple CSS. And I just did "sudo apt full-upgrade" same result.  Also the sound/audio is OUT.

Comment: Best solution is installing another browser, Firefox is working without that annoying popup.

Comment: Thanks for the input about Firefox I will lookup the install command for it and try it out.
Curious to see how it renders/supports CSS3 style (eg. flexbox flexgrid).